# compare between 2 subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

```
select hr_emp_id
from hr_holidays_requests 
where (select DATEPART(YEAR, hr_to_date) from hr_holidays_requests) >
  any (select DATEPART(YEAR,hr_from_date) as stasrt from hr_holidays_requests)
```

error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: `where DATEPART(YEAR, hr_to_date) > any ...`

Comment: select DATEPART(YEAR,hr_from_date) as stasrt from hr_holidays_requests

Comment: compare between this two subquery

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. All as well formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Your subqueries are completely independent from your main query. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Correct my if I am wrong

Do you want to select all items from hr_holidays_requests where hr_to_date is geater than hr_from_date compared by the year? Maybe you are thinking a little bit too complex, hope I got correctly

```
SELECT hr_emp_id FROM hr_holidays_requests 
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, hr_to_date) > DATEPART(YEAR,hr_from_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this for comparing two colunm values .
SELECT hr_emp_id FROM hr_holidays_requests 
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, hr_to_date) > DATEPART(YEAR, hr_from_date);

Comment: How is this different from the answer already given by bnxuq?